# Updating replica in kubernetes deployment file

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment file with replicas set to 1. So when I do 'kubectl get ...' I get 1 record each for deployment, replicaset and pod.

Now I set replicas to 2 in deployment.yaml, apply it and when I run 'kubectl get ..' command, I get 2 records each for deployments, replicaset and pods each.

Shouldn't previous deployment be overwritten, hence resulting in a single deployment, and similar for replicaset(2 pods are ok as now replicas is set to 2)?

This is deployment file content:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.16
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Can you please add your deployment.yaml and eventually other relevant yaml file's related to the deployment?

Comment: What's the actual output of `kubectl get deployment`?  Did you create two Deployments with different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...Now I set replicas to 2 in deployment.yaml, apply it and when I run 'kubectl get ..' command, I get 2 records each for deployments, replicaset and pods each.`

Can you try `kubectl get deploy --field-selector metadata.name=nginx-deployment`. You should get just 1 deployment. The number of pods should follow this deployment's `replicas`.

Comment: I get this:

nginx-deployment   2/2     2            2

Comment: There's just 1 deployment named nginx-deployment. "2/2" - means 2 out of 2 pods are ready. "2" - means 2 pods are up-to-date. "2" - means 2 pods are available.

Comment: So 'kubectl get deploy' gives true picture rather than 'kubectl get deployment'. Its conusing a bit, I would say. Thanks a lot.